# Django/Python URL Regex of form "string#1"

Tags: python, regex, django, url, expression

I would like to match URL string "anything#1" in django. My regular expression goes like this:

```
r'^(?P<title>\w+[_]*)?/#(?P<id>\d+)/$'
```

The "#1" part should be optional, so I put question mark there. However it shows me an error. What am I doing bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't control signet (or fragment), you can get it in your view with [`HttpRequest.get_full_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) :

Get it only with :

```
 >>> request.get_full_path().split('#')[1]
 '1'
```